# Display another laravel blade view as a modal in a page

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

Good day everyone,
please, I am new to Laravel, I am creating a project management app, I created an index page for projects and I have a button where I can be able to create new projects, it is entirely another blade file, I need to display the blade as a modal, I tried using @include and bootstrap modal, but the index page is the one displaying in the modal popup instead of the create page, I don't know where I am getting it wrong, I need help because there is a lot of places I need to use the modal.

This is my index page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">

        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" href="{{ route('projects.create') }}" data-target="#createModal"> New Project</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <p>{{ $message }}</p>
</div>
@endif

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead class="text-primary">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach ($projects as $project)
    <tbody class="table-striped">

        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $project->introduction }}</td>
            <td>{{ $project->created_at->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('projects.destroy',$project->id) }}" method="POST">
                    <a class="fas fa-eye fa-lg text-warning mr-1" href="{{ route('projects.show',$project->id) }}"></a>
                    <a class="fas fa-edit fa-lg text-primary mr-1" href=" {{ route('projects.edit',$project->id) }}"></a>

                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

                    <button type="submit" class="fa fa-trash fa-lg text-danger" style="border: none; background-color:white;"></button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    @endforeach
</table>

{!! $projects->links() !!}

@endsection

<div class="modal fade" id="createModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createModal" data-attr="{{ route('projects.create') }}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                @include('projects.create')
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

while this is the create page

```
@extends('layouts.modal')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h2>New Project</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('projects.index') }}"> Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif

<form action="{{ route('projects.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Name:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Introduction:</strong>
                <textarea class="form-control" style="height:50px" name="introduction" placeholder="Introduction"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>location:</strong>
                <textarea class="form-control" style="height:150px" name="location" placeholder="Location"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
@endsection
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't have your whole code base but I'm guessing you should remove `@extends('layouts.modal')

@section('content')` and `@endsection` from *projects/create*

Comment: Thanks so much, that is the answer to it, it works

Comment: @NoOorZ24, .@include works for a route that does not require an id, but one of the route  that needs an id, how can I pass it using .@include
This .@include('projects.create) works,  but I am trying to do this also .@include('projects.edit', $project->id), but it seems it is not allow

Comment: Can ID be changed by pressing on different button (in same view) or is it static? If it's changing then solution is : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-related-target. If it's static then your include file is already in same scope and all variables are accessible, but if you want you can pass array of data if same modal is used in multiple views and you want to standardize passed data: `@include('view.name', ['variable' => $variable])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later figure the answer, the mistake I was doing is including the

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
```

So the page should just be the form or what you want to display without the **@extends('layouts.app')**

```
<form action="{{ route('projects.store') }}" method="POST">
@csrf

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Name:</strong>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Introduction:</strong>
            <textarea class="form-control" style="height:50px" name="introduction" placeholder="Introduction"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>location:</strong>
            <textarea class="form-control" style="height:150px" name="location" placeholder="Location"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do we need to keep the submit button inside the create page? or the outside one?
Which one will work?